# Date Picker is not working

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

This is about dynamically add multiple data and remove data. I need first field for pickup date from datepicker script.

my date picker calender is not appear when i click first field. Please check the code where i need to insert this `$("#datepicker").datetimepicker();` function for working this script.i haven't get any error.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><br />
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post" id="insert_form">
                <div class="table-repsonsive">
                    <span id="error"></span>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Enter Item Name</th>
                            <th>Enter Quantity</th>
                            <th>
                                <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td><input id = "datepicker" type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
                    html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
                    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
                    $('#item_table').append(html);
                });
                $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });
                $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var error = '';
                    $('.item_name').each(function(){
                        var count = 1;
                        if($(this).val() == ''){
                            error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
                            return false;
                        }
                        count = count + 1;
                    });
                    $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
                        var count = 1;
                        if($(this).val() == ''){
                            error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
                            return false;
                        }
                        count = count + 1;
                    });
                    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                    if(error == ''){
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"insert.php",
                            method:"POST",
                            data:form_data,
                            success:function(data){
                                if(data == 'ok'){
                                    $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                                    $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            $("#datepicker").datetimepicker();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your browser's Console/Network tab don't show errors?

Comment: no. i didn't get any errors.

Comment: Where you are using datepicker..

Comment: i already mention in my code.

Comment: but where is id="#datepicker" ?

Comment: html += '<td><input id = "datepicker" type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';

Comment: IDs have to be unique within an HTML document. If you add multiple rows on click, then you have to change the IDs used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error**

> ID always unique. You using id="datepicker" multiple times.

Make below changes in your code

This will run for sure...

**First Change**

Change `datepicker` from **id** to **class** like below.

```
html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name datepicker" /></td>';
```

Now change the script like below.

```
$(document).on('focusin','.datepicker',function(e) {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

**Working code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
        <script src="http://localhost/mercury/app/webroot/js/common/jquery-2-2-3-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><br />
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post" id="insert_form">
                <div class="table-repsonsive">
                    <span id="error"></span>
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Enter Item Name</th>
                            <th>Enter Quantity</th>
                            <th>
                                <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name datepicker" /></td>';
                    html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
                    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
                    $('#item_table').append(html);
                });
                $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });
                $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var error = '';
                    $('.item_name').each(function(){
                        var count = 1;
                        if($(this).val() == ''){
                            error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
                            return false;
                        }
                        count = count + 1;
                    });
                    $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
                        var count = 1;
                        if($(this).val() == ''){
                            error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
                            return false;
                        }
                        count = count + 1;
                    });
                    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                    if(error == ''){
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"insert.php",
                            method:"POST",
                            data:form_data,
                            success:function(data){
                                if(data == 'ok'){
                                    $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                                    $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on('focusin','.datepicker',function(e) {
                $(this).datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Using datetimepicker. But you want datepicker only` Why would you think that's the case? The OP has clearly included a 'datetimepicker' library

Comment: your code is working perfectly. but i also find easiest way to date pick.<input type="date" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name datepicker" />